# вычисления минимального элемента 4-ой строки матрицы A

Tags: pascal

Дана матрица целых чисел(5,5) Разработайте программу вычисления минимального элемента 4-ой строки матрица А.
Как в данной программе вычислить минимальный элемент 4-ой строки?

```
program Project1;
const
  maxrow = 5;
  maxcol = 5;
var
  a: array[1..maxrow,1..maxcol] of real; { Переменная для хранения массива.}
  i,j: integer; { Вспомогательные переменные для организации циклов.}
 
begin
  for i:= 1 to maxrow do
    for j:= 1 to maxcol do
    begin
      write('Введите значение элемента [',i,',',j,']: ');
      Readln(a[i,j]);         { Ввод значений в двумерный массив.}
    end;
      writeln('Исходная матрица: ');
  for i:= 1 to maxrow do
    begin
      for j:= 1 to maxcol do
        write(a[i,j]:7:2);    { Вывод двумерного массива в консоль.}
      Writeln;
    end;
    Begin
    jmax:=1;n:=4;
    For j:=2 to m do
     if A[n,j]>A[n,jmax] then jmax:=j;
    Max:=A[n,jmax];
End;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
program Project1;
const
  maxrow = 5;
  maxcol = 5;
var
  a: array[1..maxrow,1..maxcol] of real; { Переменная для хранения массива.}
  i,j: integer; { Вспомогательные переменные для организации циклов.}
  min: real;
 
begin
  for i:= 1 to maxrow do
    for j:= 1 to maxcol do
    begin
      write('Введите значение элемента [',i,',',j,']: ');
      Readln(a[i,j]);         { Ввод значений в двумерный массив.}
    end;
      writeln('Исходная матрица: ');
  for i:= 1 to maxrow do
    begin
      for j:= 1 to maxcol do
        write(a[i,j]:7:2);    { Вывод двумерного массива в консоль.}
      Writeln;
    end;
    min := real.MaxValue;
    for j:=1 to maxcol do
      begin
         if a[4,j] < min then min := a[4,j];
      end;
    write(min);
End.
```

Comment: тут надо минимальный элемент найти, а тут максимальный у вас
Не пойму как минимальный найти

Comment: @IlyaFilimonov ой, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Всё супер спасибо